# Jmeter chrome webdriver - set pageloadstrategy to none

Tags: jmeter, pageloadstrategy

in Jmeter jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config default configuration for pageloadstrategy is normal
How i can change it to none?
i don't see an option in the Chrome driver config?
it can be set in the jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler?
I'm using javascript language.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to set it once Chrome has started, and Chrome is started by the Chrome Driver Config and being [Configuration Element it's executed before the WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) so the options are in:

1. Patch [ChromeDriverConfig](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/ChromeDriverConfig.java#L51) and add the relevant capability via [ChromeOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setPageLoadStrategy-org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy-)
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) where you will have full control over your ChromeDriver instance (you will have to start your own ChromeDriver instances and make sure they don't clash)

Comment: Thanks,Can you,share, please, an example of JRS233 sampler, groovy language, chromeDriver